# Why are really specific questions on how to create shapes in HTML not closed?

Tags: discussion

How is it that questions like <s>[how to draw a teardrop in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711203/how-do-i-create-a-teardrop-in-html)</s> are allowed, when a similarly narrow question on "how do I do X in Java" where X is some really specific business requirement would get closed as too localised (or similar)? I keep seeing more and more intricate examples popping up, where people are clearly trying to use the wrong tools for the job but they are indulged by people wrapping insane CSS to their specific purpose which would be of nearly zero use to anyone else.

EDIT: Okay, so the teardrop question was just the one I'd seen most recently and not a great example, but this one about the truck is probably more what I was wondering about: [How can I create the shape of side mirrors of a truck/lorry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355331/creating-a-truck-lorry-shape-in-css)

Comment: And breathe ...

Comment: The question asks how to create a shape *like this*, it doesn't ask how to create teardrops.  Several answerers missed that detail completely, the highly upvoted and accepted answer did not.  Once you gain a bit more rep, you can downvote whatever you are not happy with.

Comment: There's no such close reason as too localized any more. What close reason do you think would fit? It's not too broad, it's clear what's being asked.

Comment: Okay, maybe the teardrop wasn't the best example, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355331/creating-a-truck-lorry-shape-in-css and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640309/create-a-lightning-bolt-design-like-the-flash-using-css?

Comment: If "too localized" isn't a thing any more then maybe this isn't relevant but it just feels like some of these type of questions aren't going to be useful to people outside the asker.

Comment: "teardrop nonsense"?

Comment: *nearly zero use to anyone else* - I think most of the 82 people who upvoted the top answer would disagree with you, there

Comment: @jbutler483: Not everyone upvotes a post because it was useful to them, despite what the tooltip might say. There are many CSS shape questions and answers that have tons of upvotes, but how many of them see actual, real-world use? Most likely, a significant portion of the upvotes mean "wow, I didn't know this was possible with CSS!" - and there have been comments to that effect as well.

Comment: But are they upvoting because it's useful, or because the answerer has demonstrated they can write a lot of complex CSS (to be fair to most of the top answers on these, "use SVG" is usually included)?

Comment: @Persijn apologies, have edited to be a bit less confrontational.

Answer (score 12):

Granted it's pretty specific, but to those that know the technology used, it's clear that they find it interesting and challenging to provide an answer to a question like that.

The question is well formed and those that have answered have provided good quality answers that I'd say improve the site.

You never know who might want to draw a teardrop in HTML/CSS in the future, and as it stand, if you Google: **HTML Teardrop**, it's the third result.

I'd rather have slightly specific good quality content over poor quality content any day of the week.

Comment: Thanks for saying my question is well formed :)

Comment: @Persijn no problem, I would have had a bash at answering if I'd seen it.

Answer (score 6):

## Just 'not a good question'?

If you follow the 'guidelines' of [Writing The Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) by Jon Skeet, you will see this:

> Make sure it’s obvious what you’re trying to get out of the question.
> Too many “questions” are actually just statements: when I do X,
> something goes wrong.

In the above question(s) you have linked, I think It's pretty clear what's going wrong, and if that's not enough, they have images and attempts at solving it themselves. all have also explained *why* it hasn't worked for them.

---

## Not useful for other members?

A quick search on Codepen, for example, shows 60 results for the word ['teardrop'](http://codepen.io/search?q=teardrop&limit=all&depth=everything&show_forks=false) (*note, not 'waterdrop' etc*), and the first result has over 6000 views - doesn't that say at least a few people have searched for such a shape?

If you think about it, such a shape is quite common in quite a few situations (labelling/etc) - and whilst the others are more 'localised', it doesn't mean that they are **bad questions**. They show:

- an attempt
- a reason for use (whether for a star rating or otherwise)
- a **specific problem** which can be answered in a couple of paragraphs.

So that rules out the 'too broad' close-vote option.

---

## Too Localised?

Now, as for 'too localised', I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized), in which the answer contained:

> a way to close certain questions that could definitely not help anyone

Now, how exactly can you state what does and doesn't help one person or another?

I also came across:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107273/278787

which suggests EFFORT is a huge attribute to a question. I feel all linked questions (so far) have shown effort, and it is clear (via upvotes and answers) that the community is happy to answer these 'challenge' questions.

---

So, in answer to your question, the **community** decides if such a question is worthwhile or not. It is up to the community to decide whether or not a question, whether too hard or too easy, is worth retaining on the site.

I (personally) think these questions have helped at least a few people, and that has been displayed via the voting system.